# How to a plot a line for $ax+by-c$ in MATLAB?

Tags: graphing-functions, linear-programming, matlab

The title basically says it all. I'm doing an assignment and need to include a plot of my scatter and the line generated by `linprog()`.

I ran `linprog()` and got the values:

```
1.0000
1.0000
16.5000
12.5000
```

for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `f`, respectively. The equation for my line is:

```
ax + by - c = 0
```

I know it's a simple question, but I've been looking all night for an answer and nothing has presented itself. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you know the equation is linear, it can be rearranged for $y$ as $$y=\frac{c-ax}{b},$$
if $b\neq 0$. This can be plotted using

```
x = [xmin,xmax];
y = (c-a*x)/b;
plot(x,y)
```

In the case that $b=0$, the equation simplifies to $x=\dfrac{c}{a}$. This is a vertical line, which can be plotted using

```
x = (c/a)*[1,1];
y = [ymin,ymax];
plot(x,y)
```

To display the data points as well on the same graph using [scatter](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html), after running either of the above sets of commands, you can run

```
hold on
scatter(xdata,ydata)
hold off
```